# How to extract type from string

Tags: python, types

I need some way to reliably identify whether a string can be of another type eg. `"1"` would evaluate to `1` - an int, `"2.0"` would evaluate to `2.0` - a float and "John has 3 apples" would just evaluate to a string. Is there some package that does this - builtin or otherwise?

It would be great if it also worked on dates and currency

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)

```
int_type = ast.literal_eval("1")
float_type = ast.literal_eval("2.0")
```

But will only work on python literal structures: strings, bytes, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, sets, booleans, None and Ellipsis

Answer (score 3):

You can use `try/except` block for primitive types:

```py
strings = ["1", "2.0", "John has 3 apples"]

def get_value(s):
    types = (int, float, str)
    for type in types:
        try:
            return type(s)
        except ValueError:
            pass

print(get_value(strings[0]))
print(get_value(strings[1]))
print(get_value(strings[2]))
```